# contentInsets for adding padding to UIButton

Tags: swift, uikit

I want to add some padding to a button in Swift using UIButton.configuration contentInsets, but it doesn't really do anything.

Am I doing something wrong?

My button creation is:

```
    lazy var botonDescarga : UIButton = {
        let boton = UIButton(frame: .zero)
        boton.setTitle("Descargar todo", for: .normal)
        boton.backgroundColor = .white
        boton.setTitleColor(UIColor(.black), for: .normal)
        boton.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        boton.layer.borderWidth = 1
        boton.configuration?.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 10, leading: 10, bottom: 10, trailing: 10)
        return boton
    }()
```

Comment: First, don't mix `UIButton` configuration with the stateful methods. Either one or another, not both. Second you are supposed to create an instance of the configuration in the first place, and then add it to the button

Comment: @danifm1321 how did you solve this issue, can you provide your solution code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line `let boton = UIButton(frame: .zero)` button type is `.system` so configurations not gonna work, you must change configuration type

```
 boton.configuration = UIButton.Configuration.filled() // or filled,tinted,gray
```

If you don't send one of them `boton.configuration?` is nil thats why its not effect

> don't use the two together as said in the comment choose one.For example if you change it like I said and you want to set font like `button.font = ...` will not work. Choose one and use

Comment: how can you provide the code for solution, because I am trying to assign as you suggest but, it compile time error occurs, plain, filled is not available in iOS.